# Perl error: Can't call method "replace" on an undefined value MIME::Lite::HTML

Tags: perl, email

I was trying to send a mail with response from a URL using MIME::Lite::HTML. But it shows

> Can't call method "replace" on an undefined value at
>   /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/MIME/Lite/HTML.pm

The code is like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use MIME::Lite;
use MIME::Lite::HTML;
use strict;

my $mailed_html = new MIME::Lite::HTML(To => "user\@sample.com",
               From  => "admin\@sample.com",
               Subject => "Thank you mail"); # creates MIME::Lite::HTML object 
my $msg = $mailed_html->parse("http://sample.com/thankyou.html?id=19&mode=test");
$msg->send;
```

The variable `$mailed_html` have MIME::Lite::HTML object, confirmed by printing using `Data::Dumper`.

Comment: Which line number is in the error message? Which version of MIME::Lite::HTML are you using? [This bug](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=41447) was fixed in version 1.24.

Comment: The error is on calling `parse` method. MIME::Lite::HTML version is 1.24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer. Actually there was no error with the code. The request for parsing message using `MIME::Lite::HTML` was not reaching the server because of DNS resolve issue. If the request can't reach then it will return the object with no data and so replace function cannot be executed for empty data.

Thanks for your responses.